# pyLDAvis concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, version, modeling

I am using pyLDAvis for topic modeling visualization.

Python version 3.5
pyLDAvis version 2.1.2
pandas version 0.22.0

My code is as follows: 
`pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()`

```
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)
```

The error is:

`TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'`

I did some research online and it seems like pyLDAvis is dependent on pandas version 0.17.0? Are there other topic modeling visualization libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when I use pandas 0.20.3 and pyLDAvis 2.1.2. After updating pandas to 0.20.4, the problem solved.